# data class copy function not working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I have a list and finding a element on the list i.e. filtering the list according to conditon.

**MovieItemModel**

```
data class MovieItemModel(
    val name: String,
    val icon: String,
    val summary: String,
)
```

**main**

```
fun main() {

    val movieItemModelFirst = MovieItemModel("nothing 1", "url", "checking 1")
    val movieItemModelThird = MovieItemModel("nothing 2", "text", "checking 2")

    useCopyFunction(
        list = listOf(
            movieItemModelFirst,
            movieItemModelThird,
        )
    )
}
```

I have `useCopyFunction` inside that I am filtering list based on condition and creating a `NewModel`. Adding element in `NewModel` using `copy` function but it not works correclty

**useCopyFunction**

```
private fun useCopyFunction(title: String = "xyz", list: List<MovieItemModel>) {
    val newModel = NewModel(title = title)
    list.firstOrNull { it.icon != "text" }?.let { item ->
        println("item found :- $item")
        val name = item.name
        val summary = item.summary
        newModel.copy(
            name = name,
            summary = summary
        )
    }
    println("new model $newModel")
}
```

**NewModel**

```
data class NewModel(
    val title: String,
    val name: String = "",
    val summary: String = "",
)
```

when trying to print the value it looks like this

**Actual output**

```
item found :- MovieItemModel(name=nothing 1, icon=url, summary=checking 1)
result = NewModel(title=xyz, name=, summary=)
```

**Expected Output**

```
result = NewModel(title=xyz, name=nothing 1, summary=checking 1)
```

so what is wrong in `useCopyFunction` ?

Comment: Please refer: [Copying an object in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying).

Answer (score 1):

You don't do anything with the result of `newModel.copy(...)`, what you're printing is the original `newModel` object.

Comment: so how can I print the modify one?

Answer (score 0):

After @[Joffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540818/joffrey) and @[Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5990846/jay) suggestion I went to official [document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) and found the solution.

```
private fun useCopyFunction(title: String = "xyz", list: List<MovieItemModel>) {
    val newModel = NewModel(title = title)
    val olderNewModel = newModel
    list.firstOrNull { it.icon != "text" }?.let { item ->
        println("item found :- $item")
        val name = item.name
        val summary = item.summary
        olderNewModel = newModel.copy(
            name = name,
            summary = summary
        )
    }
    println("new model $olderNewModel")
}
```

Thanks guys...